# Setting specific variables from a different script

Tags: bash

I need to take specific variables from one script and use them in a different script.

Example:

Original script:

```
VARA=4              # Some description of VARA
VARB=6              # Some description of VARB
SOMEOTHERVAR="Foo"
/call/to/some/program
```

I want to write a second script that needs `VARA` and `VARB`, but not `SOMEOTHERVAR` or the call to the program.

I can already do:

```
eval $(grep 'VARA=' origscript.sh)
eval $(grep 'VARB=' origscript.sh)
```

This seems to work, but when I want to do both, like this, it only sets the first:

```
eval $(grep 'VAR[AB]=' origscript.sh)
```

because it seems to concatenate the two lines that `grep` returns. (Which probably means that the comments save the first assignments.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put quotes around it, so that the newlines in the output of `grep` will not be turned into spaces.

```
eval "$(grep 'VAR[AB]=' origscript.sh)"
```